# LM317 temperature

Tags: temperature, lm317

I recently bought this LM317, and I connect it with resistances in order to get 4.2 V: [LCSC LM317 clone product page](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Linear-Voltage-Regulators_Changjiang-Electronics-Tech-CJ-LM317_C84244.html)

The problem is when I connect it with a 12 V 500 mA power supply it gets extremely hot, like you can touch it without getting burned.

I recheck the datasheet it says that it support 1.2 A and I only use more or less 500 mA max.

- Is this normal?
- Do I have to check my schematic again?
- It is the same thing with a bigger SMD LM317?

Comment: 12V-4.2V=7.8V. 7.8V*0.5A=3.9W is dissipated by the LM317. So, thats why it becomes hot. You need quite some copper area on your PCB to cool that

Comment: Lol, I love how they even steal the example schematic pixel-by-pixel from the [Fairchild LM317 datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/LM317.pdf). Mehdi, while **every** linear regulator has to dissipate the energy difference between high input and lower output voltage times current as heat, I wouldn't trust a single number from this data sheet – someone not even willing to draw their own schematic in a data sheet is probably also not doing proper testing and thermal qualification on their components.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you propably right !!  it get extremly hot it's scaring

Comment: no, it's not, anything dissipating close to 4W in a package that size will get hot. Read Humpawumpa's answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

The LM317 is a linear regulator that means, as mentioned in the comment, it has to dissipate the energy resulting from the voltage drop between its input and the regulated output:

$$P_\text{diss}=(V_\text{in}-V_\text{out})\cdot I_\text{out}$$

The datasheet doesn't list any maximum rating for power dissipation but a maximum junction temperature 150°C. So you'd have to check the thermal information of your type and try to calculate the required cooling.

Another option would be to use a switched regulator which have a much better efficiency.

Comment: The LM317 does not dissipate the voltage difference. The correct way to say this is that it has a voltage drop across it's input and output terminals.

Comment: thx for the input :)

Comment: i will do this thank you for the support

Answer (score 1):

With Humpawumpa's [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/438745/64158) in place, we know that **every** linear regulator will produce the power \$P_\text{diss}\$ as heat. In you case, that is up to 3.9 W.

## But how much hotter does your package get?

So the Changjiang [data sheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Changjiang-Electronics-Tech-CJ-LM317_C84244.pdf) claims a thermal resistance of 5°C/W, i.e. for every watt you dissipate, your device gets 5°C warmer, if the pins of the package are connected to an infinitely good cooler. If they are not, it will be warmer.

However, that claim is wrong: It's from the [Fairchild LM317](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Changjiang-Electronics-Tech-CJ-LM317_C84244.pdf), from where also the schematic in the data sheet is stolen:

## changjiang data sheet

[image: Image from Changjiang]

## Fairchild data sheet ca 2001, drawing probably 2e1 years older

[image: Image from Fairchild]

Such low thermal resistances are achievable with large packages with large thermal contacts, such as the TO-220 package of the original LM317:

[image: TO-220 drawing, by Fairchild]

## Conclusion

So, someone simply copy-and-pasted together the datasheet of your version of the LM317. All bets are off – whoever sells these regulators clearly didn't have the intention to spend money on thermally qualifying their devices.

## Course of action

So, throw away your LM317. Instead of buying from sketchy Chinese sellers, selling sketchy chines clones of simple devices, buy from a reputable distributor selling original parts from TI, ST, On semiconductors or Analog Devices – these all actually test their chips.

Still, in your usage scenario, no matter which chip you'll buy, it'll get hot – use a switch-mode power supply instead if that bothers you.

Comment: Just a comment- LCSC (distributor) and Changjiang (manufacturer) is pretty much the equivalent of buying from a Chinese Digikey or Mouser. In no way is that like buying stuff on eBay or Aliexpress where it could be counterfeit or remarked.

Comment: I read the 5°C/W and \$P_{MAX}\$=20W and I started laughing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany didn't know that, and tbh, Changjiang's blatantly ripped-off datasheet doesn't make a strong case for that

Comment: @MarcusMüller i will check the switch mode method instead, thank you very much

Comment: is it a good practice to use switching regulator when i have a GSM/GPRS and RF in my PCB ? is it ok for the noise ?

Comment: GSM is pretty robust against switch-mode supply noise (your telephone uses dozens of switching regulators, no problem). You just need to adhere to standard practices in terms of EMI mitigation when designing your supply: Sufficient decoupling caps, short traces between transistors and drivers, short thick traces for high currents, separate RF and power section on the board, have a good ground plane, and of course do the necessary output filtering. All in all, no magic – ti.com has an excellent power designer tool that gives you a recommended design in minutes.

Comment: excellent !! thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

A heat sink must be attached with paste and screw if you want to keep your IC safe.

Comment: won't help. The junction-case thermal resistance is probably dominant here, and you can't remedy that with an external heat sink. Also, this is an SMD package that can't be screwed.