# Can I pull out 3.5W from an SOT223 LDO?

Tags: power, ldo

I'm building an LED array and I need to supply it with 12V. Each LED is in parallel, so I first want to drop out the voltage to 5V. The total intensity that would come out from the LDO would be 1A and the power would be (12V-5V)*1A=7W. I'm pretty sure that power will be pretty much impossible to supply with a single LDO, so I'm thinking on using another LDO in parallel to divide the power to 3.5W. The LDO i've selected is the [AZ1117-5.0](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AZ1117I.pdf). Will 3.5W still be too much for this component? I can see a graph in the datasheet that compares the power dissipation against the case temperature in the 2.5V version and at 3.5W, it would get to ~80ºC. I'm guessing that in the 5V version, the temperature will be less than that. Do you think I will be alright? If not, what are my options in order to keep the PCB the smallest as possible?

Comment: I'm not writing an answer, because it would be the same answer I wrote several times already, but: clear use case for a buck regulator, not a linear regulator. No matter which linear regulator you use, it will always be the expensive and wrong choice, as you would need a large and costly hear sink to get these 7 W away from chip and board.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the linear voltage regulator going hot although within its specification?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491553/why-is-the-linear-voltage-regulator-going-hot-although-within-its-specification)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/488182/lm317-vs-ams1117-as-constant-current-limiter-for-led-smd-boards/488184#488184

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/438734/lm317-temperature/438755#438755

Comment: Consider a TLVM13620. Takes most of the difficult parts of switching converter design out of the picture; all you need to do is provide a handful of capacitors and resistors following equations in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use junction-to-ambient thermal resistance, not junction to case.

For an SOT223 that's around 135°C/W so for a 40°C ambient your die would be heading for 500°C.

Use a buck regulator not a linear regulator, as @MarcusMuller suggests.

To get a small PCB you often have to use better technology. Using GaN technology we can have a 60W charger the size of a credit card and 10mm thin. You don't need anything that modern.